# log file to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a google chrome extension, is it possible to write a log file to client's machine? because when the extension will be used by clients, I want to ask them what they see at log file if there will be an error exption.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/inorganik/debugout.js

Comment: @xameeramir It writes logs only regarding current page, if I have more the one page then I neen a separate file to each page